# navigating in ionic 3 from single page to tabs and a particular view

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an Ionic 3 project I'm working on where I'm using Lazy Loading for navigation, which I think is now the default.

I have a 'Tabs' project, where at one point I want to pop out of tabs and display a single page, then I want to navigate back to a particular page and display the 'Tabs' again.

To pop out of my tabs and display a page without the tabs controller I do the following:

```
  goToSinglePage(){
    this.app.getRootNav().setRoot('SinglePage');
  }
```

The problem is I now want to go back to a particular page and display the tabs again.

I'm trying to see how to do that, but the only thing I can do is change the root nav back to the default 'Tabs' page.